# Member registration rejecting valid selection option

Tags: members, forms, fields, registration, validation

I have a member registration form with standard fields. One of them is State, which is a Select List with state abbreviations as options.

Lately, when users attempt to register, they are told `The following field contains an invalid selection: State` and invited to return to correct the form where the state is selected. Choosing any other state repeats the error. However, we can see that `m_field_id_7:IL`, for example, is in the POST request like any other field.

Why might this be happening and how can we diagnose it?

**Edit:** added images that show the nature of the form and how it behaves. It doesn't use AJAX -- just normal member fields.

[image: form and its fields]

[image: state field properties]

[image: state select in the frontend]

[image: state select, HTML, in inspector]

[image: the field being submitted in the POST request. It's not AJAX.]

[image: the error message returned by EE's validation on the error page.]

Comment: Can you throw up your form layout pls. Also, you're using generic select dropdown yes or JavaScript fancy select ?

Comment: Sure thing -- added a lot of detail as images.

Comment: Try hard coding the value to see if its the select or something else